# Adding validation rules for form fields with same name but different models

Tags: laravel, forms, validation

In my Laravel 7 app, to have nicer error messages in forms, I am using custom validations attributes. For instance for the field `id` it shows `inventory number needed` when missing in the form field for submission. Now the issue is that I have several forms for different models in my app and there is ofc more than one `id` field. There is also an `id` which is an employee number or a process number.

But in `resources/lang/en/validation.php` I don't see a way to define the same field name for different models. My idea was to rename the field for error checking, e.g. `id` rename to `employee_id` but then no error message comes up.

From my view:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('id') ? ' ' : '' }}">
  <input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('id') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="id" type="text" value="{{ old('id', $process->id) }}" aria-required="true"/>
  @include('alerts.feedback', ['field' => 'employee_id'])  //not working
</div>
```

From my validation.php:

```
    'attributes' => [ 
        'email' => 'Mail Address',
        'old_password' => 'Current Password',
        'password' => 'Password',
        'id' => 'Inventory Number', //working, for other form/model
        'employee_id' => 'Employee ID' //not working
    ]
```

I think the issue is that only field names are accepted that actually exist in the database for the model. How to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution: A much better way to define custom error attributes than in the `validation.php` is to create a form request for the model (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#creating-form-requests) and use the method `function attributes()`. So there are no conflicts with other model field names and it's more clear, because the attributes are set in the model's form request:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Employee;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class EmployeeRequest extends FormRequest
{
(...)
  public function attributes()
  {
    return [
      'id' => 'Employee ID',
    ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom messages when you validate your request, it would go something like this:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'id' => 'required',
        'employee_id' => 'required'
    ],
    [
        'id.required' => 'ID field is required',
        'employee_id.required' => 'Employee field is required'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: This is in the controller, right? It does not work with `@include('alerts.feedback', ['field' => 'employee_id'])`. What do I have to set as `employee_id` in the view to make this work? And I'm not sure if this is a good way, because `employee_id` is not the real field in the database, it's `id`. So I have to rename it back again, right?

Comment: You can try to do it in the view like this `@error('employee_id ')<div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>@enderror`

Comment: No, `@error('employee_id')<div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>@enderror` not bringing up anything (working for `title` in another field though).

Comment: It should be a good way for using custom messages, to work it is important that if you have <input type='"text" name="id"> and you want ID to be required in validator you must use the name that you defined in the name attribute of the <input>

Comment: Can you maybe edit the question with your controller and view ?

Comment: You can also do dd($errors->all()) and see if there is employee_id if yes you should be able to access it